# HashMap strange issue - duplicate objects

Tags: java, android, data-structures, hashmap

I have a simple application, that calculates what the user has ordered. The results stored in a `singleton` object where the main variable is `LinkedHashMap<Product, Integer>` - Integer holds number of times product ordered. :

```
public static synchronized Order getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null)
        INSTANCE = new Order();
    return INSTANCE;
}

private LinkedHashMap<Product, Integer> order;

private Order() {
    order = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}

//adding product to order
public void addToOrder(Product p) {
    if (order.containsKey(p)) {
        Integer i = order.get(p);
        i = i + 1;
        order.put(p, i);
    } else {
        order.put(p, 1);
    }
}

//removing item from order
public void removeFromOrder(Product p) {
    if (order.containsKey(p)) {
        Integer i = order.get(p);
        i = i - 1;
        if (i == 0) {
            order.remove(p);
        } else {
            order.put(p, i);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a Product class and a Category class in my app. All the data comes from the server in `JSON` format and than parsed and the objects created. 
Product parsing

```
private List<Product> parseJson(JSONObject productsJson) throws JSONException {
    List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray productsArray = (JSONArray) productsJson.get("products");
    for(int i=0; i<productsArray.length(); i++){
        Product p = new Product();
        p.setTitle(((JSONObject)productsArray.get(i)).get("title").toString());
        p.setPrice(((JSONObject)productsArray.get(i)).get("price").toString());
        list.add(p);
    }
    return list;
}
```

But here I face a strange issue: when I add some products (lets say beers) from the Beers activity, I can add and remove them as expected, but when I go to another Category - (another activity) - and then go back to the beers activity and add same Product I've already added - the HashMap doesn't recognize those objects, and adds them as new instead of increasing the Integer.
Please help me to resolve this issue, any other pieces of code will be attached at demand.

a Product object :

```
public class Product {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer companyId;
    private Integer categoryId;
    private String title;
    private String price;
    private boolean isExpanded = false;
    public Product(){

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return isExpanded;
    }

    public void setIsExpanded(boolean isExpanded) {
        this.isExpanded = isExpanded;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Product` override `hashCode()`?

Comment: Do your `Beer` objects implement a correct `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods?

Comment: Implement a `hashCode()` method and the HashMap shouldn't have problems with duplicate items. Implement the `equals()` for good measure as well :)

Comment: Then it is a wrong `equals` implementation. Check [this](http://www.ideyatech.com/effective-java-equals-and-hashcode/).

Comment: thanks a lot! shame I can't check a comment as correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample `hashCode()` implementation you can adapt

```
    public int hashCode() {
        //return super.hashCode();

        int result = 13;

        result = 31 * result + ( silent ? 1 : 0); //silent is boolean
        result = 31 * result + msgenum;           //msgenum is int
        result = 31 * result + type;              //type is int
        result = 31 * result + from.hashCode();   //these three are objects
        result = 31 * result + val.hashCode();    //they have valid hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + msg.hashCode();

        return result;
    }
```

As for a sample `equals()` method - i would provide, but I need more info about the class really :/

Comment: We're doing everything we have to here; using prime numbers and using all members of the class in it's hashcode. Try to do the same.